# How to convert a string to a map in velocity

Tags: velocity

I have something like:

```
set( $userPrefs = ${subscription.getUserPreferences()} )
```

`getUserPreferences()` returns a string which is actually a JSON value that is escaped.

```
doing "text" : $userPrefs returns [object]
```

I see something called a Map [here](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html#Parse)

How can I convert my data which is like:

```
$userPrefs = "{\"a\": \"b\",\"c\": \"d\"}"
```

into a map?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of doing this would be to put a JSON deserializer tool in your context.

This said, if you have access to VelocityTools in your context, then you can indeed do something with the $render tool:

```
#set($raw = '{"foo":"bar", "baz":5}')
#set($assign = "${esc.hash}set($map = $raw)")
$!render.eval($assign)
#if($map)JSON parsing succeeded: map=$map #else JSON parsong failed #end
```

But this approach looks rather hackish, plus the Velocity literal map syntax is not strictly in conformance with JSON, especially around escaping. You *should* rather use a proper JSON deserializer tool.

Answer (score 1):

Thxs I can do it too :-)

```
Test
#set($raw = '{"foo":"bar", "baz":5}')
#set($assign = "$escapetool.getHash()set($map = $raw)")
#evaluate($assign)
Test (must display bar value) : $map.foo
```